# What do we mean by Pressure is same but forces are different?

Tags: forces, pressure, fluid-statics

I was reading about Fluids, where I cam came across this line:-

```
If two containers are filled to the same height, they have **equal pressures at the bottom**, even though the **forces on the bottom would be different**.
```

So what do we exactly mean by forces are different, but the resulting pressure is same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse pressure *exerted* on a surface with hydrostatic pressure, $P(h)$ or the pressure at a certain depth.  Note that as per Bernoulli's equation, the pressure in a fluid at depth $h$ is $$P(h)=P_0+\rho gh$$

So what determines pressure in a container of fluid (in equilibrium) is $h$ and is the *same in every direction*.

The quote above refers to the fact that for two different containers of the same fluid/height with different areas at the bottom, the forces *exerted on the bottoms* can differ since

$$F=P\cdot A$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ F = P \times A $$

If the areas ($A$) of the bottoms are different, the forces will differ. It's not a very clear statement.

Comment: Let's say we have different containers, i.e.. surface area of both of them are different...